# Error Prisma with Supabase ; db error: FATAL: server login has been failing

Tags: postgresql, prisma, supabase

I recently started using Prisma and I wanted to use it with supabase so I created my schema and settings up all environement variables but when I migrate here is the error (The password is correct in my .env)

```
Error: db error: FATAL: server login has been failing, try again later (server_login_retry)
   0: migration_core::state::DevDiagnostic
             at migration-engine\core\src\state.rs:269
```

And here is my schema.prisma :

```js
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
  shadowDatabaseUrl = env("SHADOW_DATABASE_URL")
}

model Items {
  i_id        Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  i_name      String
  i_image     String
  i_quantity  Int
}
```

Comment: Look in the postgresql server's log file to get it's view of the issue.

Comment: Do you get this error when invoking `npx prisma migrate dev` command?
What is your prisma version?

Comment: Yup, when using `npx prisma migrate dev` and I'm using prisma 4.10.0
I checked the logs and I have this error : `unsupported frontend protocol 16.0: server supports 3.0 to 3.0`

Comment: It sounds like something is connecting to PostgreSQL but is expecting to be connected to something else.  I don't what else, though, I've not seen that protocol number before.

Comment: Have you tried to check for network-bans in the CLI?  `supabase network-bans get --project-ref xxxxx --experiemental`

Also, I recommend using `prisma db push` instead as it works for me here.

Comment: I'm using supabase online I'm not hosting it myself so I don't know where I can allow ip's

Comment: Do you get this same error with `npx prisma db push`?

Comment: It works with `npx prisma db push` Thanks